# iOS Swift Parse This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, parse-platform

```
for index = 1; index < 53; index++ {
        self.query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(weekDataIDS[index]){  (allInOne: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in 
    //Data comes here
    //saves a lot of colums in parse

    } 
}
```

well i know getting object in background can't be too fast can i do something like;

Data comes and set in app, then return to for loop

Comment: and the error code "This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done"

Comment: I guess you wanna do it synchronously? But that way, you will have your main thread waiting for the network. The problem here is you are starting 53 asynchronous calls.

Comment: is there another way you can perform the query that you want without doing 53 individual ID queries?  That seems excessive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create multiple requests and store them all. Or, write some cloud code to do the requests in 1 shot.

Comment: multiple requests should work i guess i thought i may do it with query.getObjectWithId(weekDataIDS[index]) but it didn't work either